# View a chart by using data from access database in VB

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I want to view a chart for the data in my database
I tried this code but I got an error message

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Chart1.Series.Add("Total number of Orders for each Company")

    Dim Conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
    Dim provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    Dim dataFile = "F:\College Files\Co-op Files\Aramco Project\Application\OrdersApplication\OrdersApplication\Database.accdb"
    Conn.ConnectionString = provider & dataFile
    Conn.Open()

    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [CompanyID], (SELECT COUNT(QuantityRequired) FROM Order_Details) FROM [Orders] ", Conn)
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        Chart1.Series("Total number of Orders for each Company").Points.AddY(dr("CompanyID").ToString, dr("QuantityRequired").ToString)
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()

End Sub
```

The error message say that QuantityRequired is an Additional Information in this line

```
        Chart1.Series("Total number of Orders for each Company").Points.AddY(dr("CompanyID").ToString, dr("QuantityRequired").ToString)
```

When I remove COUNT it show up, but I need it to count the quantity required by each company ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You miss the alias giving the field name:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT [CompanyID], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order_Details) As QuantityRequired FROM [Orders] ", Conn)
```

Just guessing. SQL to read:

```
"SELECT [CompanyID], (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Order_Details AS T WHERE T.OrderId = Orders.Id) As QuantityRequired FROM [Orders]"
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but the results are wrong in the chart I don't know why

Comment: I guess you need to filter on ther Order ID. See edit.